# How to Implement Sever Client Programming using socket in which the server is sending message to client without getting Request from client?

Tags: c++, udp

one send to method from server to client and server acknowledge back to client .
and another message which server can send to client.
so will it require two socket or only one socket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with single socket, but you will need more complex approach.

If you work in single thread you'll have to check the socket, if there is some waiting read, repeatedly, but it must be with a none block check, it can be done easily with `select` system call with timeout=0 or some very short period.

Another solution can be a multi-threaded solution, when a single socket accessed from 2 threads, when one thread deal with sending request/responses, and the other with receiving request/responses from the server. both threads should be dedicated to the networking, the receiver wait on `recv` to read from the socket and fill some job packet queue, the sender wait on something like a packet queue, take packets from it, and `send` them via the socket. and some other thread take packets from the in queue, process them and if needed write to the out queue, other thread may add requests from the user to the out queue, and so on...

In any way you must define some protocol which distinct between request to responses.